# PHP MySQL Indexes

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I want to know on Indexes.

I want to create an index on one of MySQL Tables *(number of rows is 300,000)*. Here, are some columns

- item_id (primary key)
- item_name
- categoryid
- date_added
- impressions
- visits

I want to create index on `categoryid` column. I have read in other posts that update, insert, delete makes processing slow because MySQL recreates indexes on every update. 
So below are my queries:

1. What does update here means?
2. Does it mean an update to any column of any row or update to that
   particular indexed column (categoryid here).

   Because in this case when ever an item is shown in search results an impression will be incremented and if user visits item's page then visits will be incremented.
3. So, does this updation in impressions and visits will recreate the
   index (categoryid) every time (categoryid does not changes on
   updates) or it will only recreate index when categoryid is updated
   or new row is added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be update the only when you change categoryid is updated or new row is added if you have created the index on the categoryid... It will update the mapping table where this indexing manage...

Comment: So, it means that I can create an index on categoryid without worrying about recreation of indexes due to frequent updates on impressions and visits. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

how ever it depends on...indexing is a way of optimization. 
First of all you can identify slow queries with this entry: **log-slow-queries long_query_time = value** in my.cnf
This gives you an idea if there is a need for optimization.

Next let MySQL explain the query. 
the most valueable is **possible_keys**: item_name, categoryid and the used keys **key**: item_name and look if there is: using_filesort. The last one (using_filesort) says you should use an index to save response time

But!, because there is one key per table used is also worth to think about aggregation in some ways:

**Combined index:**

- *(categoryid, item_name)* when your *WHERE* part is `categoryid="iao" AND item_name="xyz"`
- *(item_name, categoryid)* when your *WHERE* part is `item_name="xyz" AND categoryid="iao"`

---> the order is important!

if your *WHERE* part is `item_name="xyz" AND categoryid="iao"` the use of two indexes:
1. index: item_name helps saving time
2. index: categoryid is lost time

the most benefit of using combined index you will get when your *WHERE* part make use of `ORDER BY` e.g.: *WHERE* part is `item_name="xyz" AND categoryid="iao" ORDER BY date_added`. In this case combined index: *(item_name, categoryid, date_added)* save time.

And yes do it the right way:
indexing consume time by indexing (`DELETE, UPDATE, REPLACE, INSERT`) and save time on each `SELECT`

Comment: I don't agree with the following statement:
"combined index: (categoryid,item_name) when your WHERE part is categoryid="iao" AND item_name="xyz" or combined index: (item_name, categoryid) when your WHERE part is item_name="xyz" AND categoryid="iao" --- the order is important!"
because for the WHERE part doesn't matter an order of the key parts.
Ie, for the **categoryid="iao" AND item_name="xyz"** and for the **item_name="xyz" AND categoryid="iao"** will be used an one key. Test this with the EXPLAIN operator

Answer (score 0):

When you index a column, any changes to values in that column will take "longer" to process because the index has to rebuilt/resorted, although this change will hardly be noticeable unless you are dealing with millions of records. On the flipside, having the index means searching on those columns will be many times faster. Its a tradeoff you need to make but usually the index is worthwhile if you are searching on those fields.